# Get object from array based on max property

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspredicate

I have an array of objects that have properties. I need to get the objects that `<=` a value.

My `[timeLog time]` is in seconds, so I need to convert it to minutes then compare it to `Object.conversion_factor`. I ultimately want the max `conversion_factor` that is `<=` the minutes of `[timeLog time]`

Is this the best approach of is there a better way (doing all this in a single predicate)?

```
+ (NSNumber *)getTimeUnitForTimeLogEntry:(TimeLog *)timeLog
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeUnit"
                inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"conversion_factor <= %i", [OnTimeClasses getMinutesFromTime:[timeLog time]]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSNumber *returnValue;
    NSArray *array = [[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);
    if (array != nil) {
        NSInteger unit = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.conversion_factor"] integerValue];
        NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"conversion_factor == %i", unit];
        [request setPredicate:finalPredicate];
        NSArray *array = [[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSLog(@"New array: %@", array);
        TimeUnit *timeUnit = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        returnValue = [timeUnit id];
    }
    else {
        NSString *message = @"Unable to find a good time unit for entry.";
        NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Error" defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@", message];
        [alert runModal];
    }

    return returnValue;
}

+ (NSInteger)getMinutesFromTime:(NSString *)time
{
    double minutesFloat = [time doubleValue] / 60;
    NSInteger minutes = round(minutesFloat);

    return minutes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a sort descriptor that sorts *descending* by your attribute, and limit the number of results to one:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"conversion_factor <= %i", [OnTimeClasses getMinutesFromTime:[timeLog time]]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"conversion_factor" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
[request setFetchLimit:1];
```

The fetch request then returns the one object with the maximum value of `conversion_factor` that is less than or equal to the given value, or an empty array if no matching object was found.